# Background is higher then textfield

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

Background is higher than textfield.
[image]

How Can I fix that?
Code:
[image]

I played with padding. but it is not about it. i added column outside "OutlinedTextField" but it didnt worked.
I want to make textfield same size with background.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the background color using **colors** attribute in **OutlinedTextField** instead of modifier background as below code

```
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(
                    top = 10.dp,
                    start = 10.dp,
                    end = 10.dp,
                    bottom = 10.dp
                ),
            label = { Text("Input") },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                focusedBorderColor = Green,
                unfocusedBorderColor = Yellow,
                backgroundColor = your_background_color
            ),
        )
```